# dxf to pdf in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, converters, dxf

Do you know a library that can convert a dxf file to pdf without having the autocad program installed ?

I'm looking to convert microsoft document too, but i know I can use the microsoft dll installed when you have office

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- QCAD v3 has an utility called dwg2pdf which also can convert from dxf files. But the dwg/dxf importer requires a (reasonable priced) licence.
- Inkscape has a command line option to convert to pdf. But currently it seems to have bug. It opens a confirmation popup even in no gui mode.
- libreOffice can also convert dxf to pdf, but the result is not satisfying. The old oo convert via unoconv did yield better result.

There are other windows only solution I don't have experience with.